# How to create a new value in a object with window

Tags: javascript

I have the object :

```
var obj = new Object()
obj.a...
```

I want create a new value for obj, obj.b. How do I do it with window.variable ? I tried window.obj["b"] = ... but it didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I do it with window.variable ?

```js
window.bot = new Object();
window.bot.a = 'foo';
window.bot['b'] = 'bar';
console.log(window.bot);
```

```js
window.bot = {'a': 'foo','b': 'bar'};
console.log(window.bot);
```